# Python Process completion

Tags: python, process, queue

So right now I am attempting to create a Python program that executes a series of tasks (Process subclasses). One of the things that I would like to know is when a Process has completed. Ideally, what I would want to do is have the Process subclass make a callback to the calling process in order to add the next Process into a queue. Here is what I have so far:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

class Task1(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
            super(Task1, self).__init__()
            self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
            print 'Start Task 1'
            time.sleep(1)
            print 'Completed Task 1'
            # make a callback to the main process to alert it that its execution has completed


class Task2(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
            super(Task2, self).__init__()
            self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
            print 'Start Task 2'
            time.sleep(1)
            print 'Completed Task 2'
            # make a callback to the main process to alert it that its execution has completed             

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()

    p1 = Process1(queue)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()

    # need a callback of some sort to know when p1 has completed its execution in order to add Process2 into the queue
```

Prior to Python, I mainly worked with Objective-C. I am mainly trying to find something for Process that is analogous to a completion block. Thanks.

Comment: afaik `.join()` will block until the child thread finishes ... (e.g. it is finished on the line after `p1.join()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are first class citizens in Python, so you can just pass them as arguments,
e.g. to your task constructors:

```
def __init__(self, queue, callb):
        super(Task2, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.callb = callb
```

You can then call them after the run method finished:

```
def run(self):
        print 'Start Task 2'
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'Completed Task 2'
        self.callb(self)
```

Define a function somewhere, e.g.

```
def done(arg):
    print "%s is done" % arg
```

And pass it to the task constructor:

```
p1 = Task1(queue, done)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, your code already does what you want it to do!
The `p1.join()` will block the main process until `p1` finishes. If `p1.join()` returns without error, then the process must have terminated and you can immediately start `task2`. Your "callback" would simply be a check that `p1.join()` has returned correctly!
From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html):

> join([timeout])
>   Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs.
>
> If timeout is None then there is no timeout.
>
> A process can be joined many times.
>
> A process cannot join itself because this would cause a deadlock. It is an error to attempt to join a process before it has been started.

Edit:
Optionally, if you want a non-blocking solution, you can poll a particular process to see if it has terminated:

```
p1.start()
while(p1.is_alive()):
    pass #busy wait
p2.start()
```

This will do exactly the same as with `p1.join`, but with this you can replace the `pass` with useful work while waiting for `p1` to complete.

Comment: +1 although you may want to offer a polling solution as well (eg `not p1.isRunning()`)